# Simplesamlphp 403 Forbidden when try to authenticate as SP

Tags: simplesamlphp

I installed 2 of the simplesamlphp program (1 as IDP and the other as SP) in my sharing host using method 13.1 in the installation documentation due to my site being a shared hosting account and unable to symlink the directory. 
https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.13/simplesamlphp-install

When I tried authentication testing from the sp site (sp.test.com/simplesaml/), it shows '403 Forbidden' but if test as idp (idp.test.com/simplesaml) the authentication page work and will redirect to the login page.

Tried changing POST to Redirect, remove .htaccess, changing to another type of authentication but still showing the 403 forbidden when clicking the  authentication link.

Anyone have any idea on fixing this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have solved the issue. 
Contacted hostgator and they had whitelist mod security rule that being hit by the script. So now working fine.

Comment: Thank you friend! You have no idea how much time you saved me!